# Django Rest Framework how to custom a nested serializer with multiple objects

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have the following serializer that retrieves pages in a set of books:

```
class PagesDataSerializer(Serializer):
   books = Book.objects.all()
   data = PagesSerializer(many=True,data=books)
```

I would like to introduce a filter (query parameter type received in the get request)
In order to access self.request content I have to add a custom function
I tried something like this:

```
class PagesDataSerializer(Serializer):

   books = Book.objects.all()
   data = PagesSerializer(source='get_pages_set', many=True)

   def get_pages_set(self, obj):
       selected_books = Book.objects.filter(type=self.request.type)
       return PagesSerializer(many=True,data=selected_books).data
```

But this doesn't work for some reason (I get empty results).... could anyone enlighten me please ?

Thank you very much

Comment: If you are just filtering the whole `Book` model then why not do it in the view level? Also, your serializer has many issues, it is not clear what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to retrieve a set of pages from specific books, PagesSerializer structures the set of pages. could you please explain to me the issues in my code ? thanks a lot

Comment: If you want to filter those specific books, you can do it on the view level by overriding `get_queryset` method of your view. And you don't need to pass the `data` argument when defining a serializer field. And the `get_pages_set` is redundant, it is only useful when your field is a `SerializerMethodField`. You should probably refer to http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer to know more